# WPF FlowDocument GridView

Tags: wpf, gridview, flowdocument

Is it possible to use a `GridView` in a `FlowDocument`? I'd need to be able to change the color of the header, perhaps even change the color of alternate rows. I've never used `FlowDocument`s before, but before jumping in, I need to know if this is possible; if not I'll have to look for a different solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but you need to wrap it in a BlockUIContainer.  Fair warning, I have not tried this.  I have only read about it.

```
<BlockUIContainer>
   <!-- Ordinary WPF controls here -->
</BlockUIContainer>
```